# highlight text range which is mixed 2 paragraph

Tags: javascript, range, selection

```
<p class="can-select">these are para1 and para2</p>

<p class="can-select">         
   <span>these are</span>
   <span>para1</span>
   <span>and</span>
  <span>para2</span>
</p>
```

And How can I select and "highlight" text "are para1 and para2" in general cases.